# Origin of the verb form "(я) ем"

Tags: глаголы, история-языка

Can please someone explain the origin of "-м" in "(я) ем".

Why do other verbs have "-у (-ю)" ending in the 1st person singular of present ("я работаю, я учу"), but this verb has "-м"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, there are some other irregular verbs.

Wikipedia [claims](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5) that:

> Нехарактерную для глаголов I и II спряжений систему окончаний
>   (архаическую) имеют глаголы *есть, надоесть, дать, создать* (и их
>   приставочные производные: *переесть, заесть, сдать, отдать, предать,
>   воссоздать* и др.), а также обсценный глагол *ссать (сцать)* (спряжение
>   на -ы-).

As for why is this so, well, irregular verbs in any language are traces of old grammar constructions, and not all of them can be logically explained.

Even in [Old Russian](http://window.edu.ru/library/pdf2txt/112/22112/5339/page7) such verbs had been pretty rare:

> К нетематическим (V класс) относилось всего пять глаголов: *быти, дати,
>   ѣсти ‘кушать’, вѣдѣти ‘знать’ и имати*. В 1-ом лице ед. ч. у этих
>   глаголов было окончание –мь (*есмь, дамь, ѣмь, вѣмь, имамь*), во 2-ом
>   лице ед. ч. – окончание –си (*еси, даси, ѣси, вѣси*, но *имаши*); в оcтальных лицах окончания были те же, что и у тематических глаголов.

So, to conclude, this is remnant of `-мь` ending.

Comment: May I ask a follow-up question: where does the Old Russian -мь come from?

Comment: @Olga, Anixx already answered this, just want to add that, as far as I understand, `am` in English "I am" and, "am" in Armenian "yes am" (which also translates I am) share same roots with verb ending `-mi` in PIE

Comment: @habunc yes, I amended my answer.

Answer (score 7):

This ending came from Proto-Indo-European athematic indicative singular first person verb ending -mi. The PIE word for "(I) eat" was ***e̯ed-mi***

You can see an example of full PIE verb declension here:
http://pie.allderek.com/doku.php?id=steh%E2%82%82

The same ending gave the English form *"(I) am"* from the PIE form of the verb ***e̯es-mi***.

Answer (score 0):

Now let's take a look at a broader scope. First, at two ancient IE languages, Sanskrit and Tocharian.

The endings would be the following.

1. for **Tocharian** (B-dialect, which is the most ancient one):

   > yamaskau = I make/do
   > yam = I go
   > nasam = I am (A-dialect)
2. for **Sanskrit**:

   > लट्लकार (present tense): भवामि [bhavaami] = I am [for someone else's benefit]
   > लङ्लकार (past tense):    अभवम् [abhavam] = I was [for someone else's benefit]
   > लृट्लकार (future tense): भविष्यामि [bhaviShyaami] = I will/shall be [to someone else's benefit]
   > विधैलिङ्लकार (optative): भवेयम् (bhaveyam) = I may be [to someone else's benefit]
3. for **Hittite**:

   > esmi = I am
   > epmi = I take
   > edmi = I eat
   > istamasmi = I hear

and the like.

This is a common personal ending for (Proto-)Slavic and some (non) Indo-European 1st. p. sg. present. For example, in Polish the 1st. p. sg. for present tense is a regular paradigm for a certain type of verbs (alongside with the -ę 1st person sg. for verbs of another type), e.g.

> być (to be) => ja jestem
> czytać (to read) => ja czytam
> wiedzieć (to know) => ja wiem

In Bulgarian, which, like most of languages at Balkanian area has no verb infinitives, there is also a regular м-paradigm:

> аз съм (I am)
> аз обичам (I like/love)
> аз искам (I want)
> аз отварям (I open [smth])

We might also compare this to Ghaelig grammar, e.g. the Irish

> táim (or tá mé) = I am
> beannaím = I bless

or with personal prepositions at the same language:

> agam = at me/I have
> dom = to/for me
> fúm = concerning me

and the like.

The Lithuanian, on the other hand, provides, to the best of my knowledge, almost exclusively the vowel 1st. p.sg. present ending paradigm. In general, the ancient languages provide three different paradigms:

1. m-paradigm, present in most of the IE-languages (either synthetically or as a result of later agglutination process, see the Irish example)
2. vowel-paradigm (sometimes combined with alternative glottoral consonants) and
3. n-paradigm (which is regular for modern Finnish and Estonian. e.g.)

> olen = I am (same in Estonian)
> haluan = I want (Estonian: tahan)
> tarvitsen = I need (the Estonian structure is different, so here is another example: ma sõidan = I travel, I ride)
> jatkan = I continue (Estonian jätkan)

Cf. with ni for 1st p.sg. in Basque, Mongolian and Finnish (personal form of nouns).

Comment: -1. Finish and Estonian are not Indo-European languages, PIE had only two paradigms: thematic and athematic.

Comment: Have you noticed the brackets at words (non) Indo-European?

Comment: And we do not have any texts in PIE (to which, by the way, I have made no reference).

Comment: "In general, the ancient languages provide three different paradigms" - there are much more different paradigms in ancient languages. The n-paradigm has nothing to do with Indo-European languages.

Comment: Could you please provide some more examples of these paradigms? And what about the -n paradigm in Germanic langiages?

Comment: This needs sources cited, and to be put in context. Please add them.

Comment: This does not need any sources citied, since the exaples are taken from my language competence.

Comment: Is it 100% correct to say that languages which are not related have some common endings? I would be more cautious and I would just say they coincide. If you want to say that it might be more than a coincidence, say it out loud. It is hard (for me) to infer it from examples only.

Comment: It is hard to postulate any common origin for Tocharian and Finno-Ugric languages. Yet there are some similarities between these languags in case paradigms (including number of cases), grammar and even sytax. Not mentioning some words of presumably common stock for Tocharian, Sanskrit and Finno-Ugric languages. Besides, proto-Tochars and some Finno-Ugric tribes might have a common territory shared. Millenia and millenia ago, somewhere.

Comment: @Manjusri Ok, we don't really know what you actually know. So I had to ask. By the way, even if you know those things, it's always good to provide references so that people that want to read more can go and learn more about it and it helps backing up your answer (which also means more upvotes). :D